# How to use JTabbedPanel with JPanel in differents classes?

Tags: swing, user-interface, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to develop a Swing application which composed of a window with differents tab (in fact, each tab is an independant form).

So I want to separate the code of the different forms in different class.

I use a GUI form in IntelliJ. So first I created a principal form (a `JFrame`) which contains a `JTabbedPane`. I created some other forms with their own java class in the same way. These forms are `JPanel`.

Principal.form :

[image]

And the related java class :

```
public class Principal extends JFrame {
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane1;

// Pour le panel Principal
private JPanel panel1;
private JLabel nouveaute_1;
private JLabel nouveaute_2;
private JLabel nouveaute_3;
private JLabel repas_midi;
private JLabel repas_soir;
private JLabel date_du_jour;

// Pour les autres onglets
private JPanel panel_creation = new CreationRecette();

public Principal() {
    init();
    this.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane1);
    init_panel_creation();
}



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void init(){
    this.setTitle("CookApp");
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void init_panel_principal(){
    // Affichage de la date du jour
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    date_du_jour.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

    //TODO Affichage des 3 dernières nouveautés (date, qui, update/création, quoi)

    //TODO Affichage du repas du midi et du soir
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



private void init_panel_creation(){
    tabbedPane1.add("Création", panel_creation);
}
```

}

CreationRecette.form :

[image]

The related code for creationRecette.form :

```
public class CreationRecette extends  JPanel {
private JTextField text_nom_recette;
private JComboBox combo_type;
private JComboBox combo_tps_preparation;
private JComboBox combo_tps_cuisson;
private JComboBox combo_thermostat;
private JTextArea text_ingredients;
private JTextArea text_recette;
private JButton bouton_valider;
private JComboBox combo_nb_part;
private JTextField text_source;
private JPanel panel_creation;
private JLabel label_nom_recette;
private JLabel label_source;
private JLabel label_type;
private JLabel label_tps_preparation;
private JLabel label_tps_cuisson;
private JLabel label_thermostat;
private JLabel label_nb_part;
private JLabel label_ingredients;
private JLabel label_recette;



public CreationRecette() {
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

So now, I can display the principal form without issue. I try to insert the differents others form/`Jpanel` in the `JTabbedPane`. So when I execute the main, I have my principal form plus the different tabs which are the different forms. So I think at the `principal.java`, I put the good things in place.

Execution of the app :

[image]

But my problem is all that forms are empty (except principal). For example, I created with the GUI form all my "creationRecette" form. It creates an auto generated code in `creation.java`. But if I didn't put `this.add(component1)` .... I can't see the different components in my form. I think there is another solutions, because the components are not displayed as I wish (like in the `creation.form`)

I don't understand why the main form is displayed correctly but I can't do the same with the other tab.

Can you help me ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok, I will try this evening. Thx